# Blender freeze after 120-150 Frames rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, optimization

my blender freeze after rendering an animation after 120-150 Frames.
This is really weird, because It never happens on my 980 ti, and now I've got a 3090 rtx and it freezes.
Somebody have an idea?
In the Scene is no particle, hair or simulation. So it's really weird for me.

Comment: Check the console for any errors. You can do this by going to (Window > Toggle System Console) Blender should open it's terminal in another OS window, revealing any program errors there might be.

Comment: ok I open it and will wait till it freeze again, hope I will see it 
Thanks

Comment: No, it does not show why it's freezes, but I looks like that blender freezes before it starts to go throw the comp tree maybe not. I don't know.

this is my cpu:
Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-10900KF CPU @ 3.70GHz   3.70 GHz
32 gb Ram
3090 rtx

Comment: Could you upload a blend-file that we can take a look at to possibly see what might be causing the issue.

Comment: here you can download it, on blender-exchange it don't work https://we.tl/t-1n4Kbq6pJ6

Comment: You may not be aware of this, but Blender Stack Exchange does have a site tool for uploading blend-files. https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Oh, and unrelated to your issue, you seemed to be missing movie/image files, probably because you forgot to pack the assets before uploading it. So in conclusion, I can not help further to debug your problem except to maybe ask what exactly do you have going on between the frames you mentioned, 120-150, any key-frame animations?

Comment: when I upload it on blend-exchange.com I get this error There was an internal error attempting to complete your request.

Comment: I also notice that it freeze random, it can freeze after 7 frames or after 100.

The scene is pretty simple. no particle, no simulation. Nothing big.
Have blender some problems with new rtx cards?